# Hiding variable names in function definitions

Tags: function-construction, replacement, list-manipulation

I have a problem where Table and similar functions' substitution variable name can conflict with names in my function it self.  Here's a minimal example

```
foo[a_] := 
 Probability[x > 0, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[a, 1]]
```

if i execute

```
foo[-1]//N
```

I get the correct answer (0.158655).

if I execute instead (or use Table or similar)

```
foo[x] /. x->-1
```

I get 0 because the substitution operator substitutes x into the `Probability` arguments too making foo become `Probability[-1>0,...`.

The obvious "fix" is to just not use the same variable but then I have to remember how i've defined every function I've written and if I forget i risk making a mistake that may or may not be obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way around this could be to make local `x` inside your module. Like this

```
foo[a_] := Module[{x}, 
  Probability[x > 0, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[a, 1]]]
```

And now you can do

```
foo[-1] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
foo[x] /. x -> -1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

This is the purpose of [Formal Symbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264).  They are special symbols that can not be set to a value so that they will not clash with variables in your code. For formal lowercase x you enter <kbd>Esc</kbd>$x<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
foo[a_] := 
 Probability[\[FormalX] > 0, \[FormalX] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[a, 1]]
```

Which looks like the image below in a notebook.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

With this the variable `x` can be set a value and it will not clash with `\[FormalX]` in `foo`.

```
x = 5;
foo[0]
```

> ```
> 1/2
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good feature to know about, but it appears that they can be subject to substitution rules.  From you link: "Specific values for formal symbols can be substituted using replacement rules."

Comment: @user1816847 Of course they can be replaced by `Replace*` functions.  Under what condition would you expect a replacement not to replace?